# Alamofire 4.0 ambiguous reference on upload

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

I am trying to upload using alamofire, I am using the following code:

```
Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, to: urlRequest.1, method: .put)
            .uploadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.utility) { progress in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            }

            .responseJSON { response in
            //Some code here

        }
```

Where `urlRequest` is a tuple: `(URLConvertible, Data)`. I am getting the compiler error : `"Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:)'"`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the `headers` parameter:

```
Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, to: urlRequest.1, method: .put, headers: nil)
.uploadProgress { progress in 
        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")  
}
```

while a tuple's types should stand in this order: `(Data, URLConvertible)`

Comment: Same result adding that in.

Comment: Haven't you set indices of the tuple in reversed order?

Comment: It was the tuple index thanks! Though now I have an error on the progress:

Comment: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Progress'`